# Sum of squares of binomial coefficients

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I came across the following sum [in reference to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434933/proving-sum-n-infty-infty-e-pi-n2-frac-sqrt4-pi-gamma-left)

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{5 n}} \binom{2 n}{n}^2 = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma \left( \frac{3}{4}\right)^2}$$

The sum on the left was generated from expanding the square root in the integrand of the following elliptic integral:

$$K\left( \frac{1}{2}\right) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-\frac12 \sin^2{\theta}}} $$

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to evaluate this sum directly.  Mathematica has no problem in doing so.  Can someone point the way?

Comment: Are you sure that first equality is correct? When I evaluate the LHS in Mathematica I get $\dfrac{\Gamma[1/4]}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \,\Gamma[3/4]}$ as the output.

Comment: @Orangutango: use the reflection formula  $$\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin{\pi z}}$$

Comment: @Orangutango: I think I did leave a factor of $\pi/2$ in there by mistake, however.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant $K \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)$ because that's what you have on the right side of the equation.

$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2} \sin^{2} x}} \ dx = \sqrt{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2-\sin^{2}x}} \ dx = \sqrt{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \cos^{2} x}} \ dx$$

$$= \sqrt{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^{2}}} \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}  = \sqrt{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^{4}}} du $$

$$= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \int_{0}^{1} t^{-\frac{3}{4}} (1-t)^{\frac{-1}{2}} \ dt = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} B \left( \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \ \Gamma(\frac{1}{4})}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{4})}$$

Comment: I am using Mathematica notation, which does not square the argument in the square root.  But what you do is fine by me.

Comment: Could you show how you expanded the integrand and got that sum?

Comment: Sure.  You know the Taylor series of $(1-y^2)^{-1/2}$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2 n}} \binom{2 n}{n}$$ That then leaves you with that sum times $$\int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, \sin^{2 n}{\theta} = \frac{\pi}{2}  \frac{1}{2^{2 n}} \binom{2 n}{n}$$  The last factor of $1/2^n$ comes from the factor of $1/2$ in the square root.

Comment: The question was how to arrive to the $\Gamma$'s involved result from the sum. In another words, how to evaluate the sum ?.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to the first equation, I get the same constant with the reciprocal of the following integral:

$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{{\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt\sin(x)\sqrt\cos(x)\mathrm{d}x}$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{5n}}{2n \choose n}^{2}
     ={\root{\pi} \over \Gamma^{\,2}\pars{3/4}}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{5n}}
{2n \choose n}^{2}} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{5n}}
\bracks{{-1/2 \choose n}\pars{-4}^{n}}^{2}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{n}}{-1/2 \choose n}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{-1/2} \over z^{n +1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z\root{z + 1}}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-1/2 \choose n}\pars{1 \over 2z}^{n}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z\root{z + 1}}
\pars{1 + {1 \over 2z}}^{-1/2}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\root{z} \over z\root{z + 1}\root{z + 1/2}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &
-\int_{-1}^{-1/2}{\root{-z}\ic \over
z\root{z + 1}\root{-z - 1/2}\ic}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} -\int_{-1/2}^{0}{\root{-z}\ic \over
z\root{z + 1}\root{z + 1/2}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[2mm] & -
\int_{0}^{-1/2}{\root{-z}\pars{-\ic} \over
z\root{z + 1}\root{z + 1/2}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} -\int_{-1/2}^{-1}{\root{-z}\pars{-\ic} \over
z\root{z + 1}\root{-z - 1/2}\pars{-\ic}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &
{1 \over 2\pi\ic}\int_{1/2}^{1}{\root{z} \over
z\root{1 - z}\root{z - 1/2}}\,\dd z +
{1 \over 2\pi}\int_{0}^{1/2}{\root{z} \over
z\root{1 - z}\root{1/2 - z}}\,\dd z
\\[2mm] & +
{1 \over 2\pi}\int_{0}^{1/2}{\root{z} \over
z\root{1 - z}\root{1/2 - z}}\,\dd z -
{1 \over 2\pi\ic}\int_{1/2}^{1}
{\root{z} \over z\root{1 - z}\root{z - 1/2}}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over \pi}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1/2}{\root{z} \over
z\root{1 - z}\root{1/2 - z}}\,\dd z}
_{\ds{2\root{2\pi}\Gamma\pars{5/4} \over \Gamma\pars{3/4}}}\ =\
{2\root{2\pi} \over \pi}\,{\pars{1/4}\Gamma\pars{1/4} \over \Gamma\pars{3/4}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\root{2\pi} \over 2\pi}\,{\Gamma\pars{3/4}\Gamma\pars{1/4} \over \Gamma^{2}\pars{3/4}} =
{\root{2\pi} \over 2\pi}\,{\pi/\sin\pars{\pi/4} \over \Gamma^{2}\pars{3/4}} =
{\root{2\pi} \over 2\pars{1/\root{2}}}\,{1 \over \Gamma^{2}\pars{3/4}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbox[10px,#ffd,border:2px groove navy]
{\Large{\root{\pi} \over \Gamma^{2}\pars{3/4}}}
\approx 1.1803
\end{align}

---

The last integral is evaluated with the *replacement*
$\ds{z = \sin^{2}\pars{\theta}}$ which follows the
[${\tt @Random Variable}$ answer procedure](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/435378/85343). The identity
$\ds{{2n \choose n} = {-1/2 \choose n}\pars{-4}^{n}}$ is
[derived in this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1991085/85343).