# finding complex binomial sum in closed form

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Find sum of $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{k=0}(-1)^k2^{2k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}$

Attempt: Coefficients of $x^k$ in $(1+x)^k$ and coefficients of $x^{n-k}$ in $(1+x)^{2(n-k)}$

could some help me how to solve it, thanks

Comment: When you put "complex" in the title, I think you mean $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n}&\color{blue}{(-1)^k2^{2k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k2^{2k}[z^k](1+z)^n[u^{n-k}](1+u)^{2n-2k}\tag{1}\\
> &=[u^n](1+u)^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k2^{2k}\frac{u^k}{(1+u)^{2k}}[z^k](1+z)^n\tag{2}\\
> &=[u^n](1+u)^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\frac{4u}{(1+u)^2}\right)^k[z^k](1+z)^n\tag{3}\\
> &=[u^n](1+u)^{2n}\left(1-\frac{4u}{(1+u)^2}\right)^n\tag{4}\\
> &=[u^n](1-u)^{2n}\tag{5}\\
> &\color{blue}{=(-1)^n\binom{2n}{n}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice and we extend the upper limit of the sum to $\infty$ without changing anything, since we are adding zeros only.
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule
  \begin{align*}
  [z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)
  \end{align*}
- In (3) we apply the substitution rule of the *coefficient of* operator with $z:=-\frac{4u}{(1+u)^2}$
  \begin{align*}
  A(u)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nu^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty u^n[z^n]A(z)
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we do some simplifications.
- In (5) we select the coefficient of $u^{n}$.

Comment: Nice work. I upvoted both answers.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Many thanks, Marko! :-)

Comment: Consult my response to the challenge below.

Comment: @Markus Scheuer please explain how you write $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{k=0}$ to $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}$, thanks

Comment: @DurgeshTiwari: $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $k>n$. Since $(1+z)^n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ this is equivalent with $[z^k](1+x)^n=0$ if $k>n$, so we adding zeros only if $k>n$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Hereafter, I'll use the
>   [identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1991085/85343)
>   $\ds{{2m \choose m} = {-1/2 \choose m}\pars{-4}^{m}}$.

\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}\,2^{2k}{n \choose k}{2\bracks{n - k} \choose n - k} =
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}\,2^{2k}{n \choose k}{-1/2 \choose n - k}
\pars{-4}^{n - k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-4}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}{-1/2 \choose n - k} =
\pars{-1}^{n}\,2^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}
\bracks{z^{n - k}}\pars{1 + z}^{-1/2}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{n}\,2^{2n}
\bracks{z^{n}}\bracks{\pars{1 + z}^{-1/2}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}z^{k}} =
\pars{-1}^{n}\,2^{2n}\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1/2}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{n}\,2^{2n}{n - 1/2 \choose n} =
\pars{-1}^{n}\,2^{2n}{-1/2 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n} =
2^{2n}{2n \choose n}\pars{-4}^{-n} =
\bbx{\ds{\pars{-1}^{n}{2n \choose n}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

I would like to contribute to the collection, the challenge being that
we  use a  method that  is different  from the  two that  were already
presented. We seek to evaluate

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k 2^{2k} {n\choose k} {2(n-k)\choose n-k}.$$

We use the integral

$${2n-2k\choose n-k} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n-k+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-k+1}}
\; dz.$$

We obtain for the sum

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k 2^{2k} z^k (1-z)^k
\; dz
\\ =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}}
(1-4z(1-z))^n
\; dz
\\ =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}}
(1-2z)^{2n}
\; dz.$$

This is

$$\sum_{q=0}^n (-1)^q 2^q {2n\choose q} {2n-q\choose n}.$$

We have

$${2n\choose q} {2n-q\choose n} =
\frac{(2n)!}{q! n! (n-q)!} = {2n\choose n} {n\choose q}$$

so this becomes

$${2n\choose n} \sum_{q=0}^n (-1)^q 2^q {n\choose q}
= {2n\choose n} (1-2)^n $$

which is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
(-1)^n {2n\choose n}.}$$

Comment: Nice and instructive twist! (+1)