# Proving the divergence of $\sum {2j \choose j} (\frac14)^j$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, binomial-coefficients, divergent-series

I need to evaluate the series:$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty {2j \choose j} \left(\frac14\right)^j$$ Wolfram Alpha [claims](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=summation&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22Sum%22,%20%22sumfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22(1%2F4)%5Ek%20(2k)!%2F(k!)%5E2%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22Sum%22,%20%22sumlowerlimit%22%7D%20-%3E%220%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22Sum%22,%20%22sumupperlimit2%22%7D%20-%3E%22infinity%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22FVarOpt%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22Sum%22,%20%22sumvariable%22%7D%7D&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,%20%22summation%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D) that it is divergent by the comparison test. The partial sums graph also seems to confirm this -- however, I have no idea what I can compare the sum to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at row $2n$ in the Pascal triangle. The sum of all $2n+1$ terms is $2^{2n}= 4^n$ . Since the central binomial coefficient is the largest number in that row, we have $4^n \le (2n+1){{2n} \choose n}$.
Hence
$$
\frac{1}{4^n}{{2n} \choose n} \ge \frac{1}{2n+1} \ge \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n+1}
$$
and the divergence follows from comparison with the harmonic series.

Comment: Creative answer, thank you, but it should be "2n+1", not "n+1".

Comment: @JohnDoedoe, right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can compare to the harmonic series $\sum_j 1/j$.  Namely if $T(j) = {2 j \choose j} 4^{-j}$,
$$ \dfrac{(j+1) T(j+1)}{j T(j)} = \frac{j+1}{4 j} \frac{(2j+2)!}{(j+1)!^2} \frac{j!^2}{(2j)!}  = \frac{(j+1)(2j+2)(2j+1)}{4 j(j+1)^2} = \frac{ 2j+1}{2j} > 1$$
so that $$T(j) > \frac{T(1)}{j}$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $n\geq 2$ we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{4^n n!^2}&=&\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\\&=&\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)^2}\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}\right)^{-1}}\\&\geq&\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}}\\&\geq&\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{8}-\frac{1}{4n}\right)}\\&\geq &\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2n}}\left(1-\frac{1}{9n}\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$
and a similar inequality holds in the opposite direction, too. It follows that
$$ K_1\sqrt{N}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n} \leq K_2 \sqrt{N} $$
for two positive constants $K_1,K_2$. Actually:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{N+1}{2\cdot 4^N}\binom{2N+2}{N+1}\sim\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sqrt{N}. $$

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stirling's formula to find an asymptotic for $\binom{2j}j$.

Alternatively use
$$\frac1{\sqrt{1-x}}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{2j}j\frac{x^j}{4^j}.$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: for the finite sum is hold $$ \sum_{j=0}^m \binom{2j}{j}=2\,{\frac { \left( m+1 \right)  \left( 2\,m+2 \right) !\, \left( 1/4
 \right) ^{m+1}}{ \left(  \left( m+1 \right) ! \right) ^{2}}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
[Indeed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1991085/85343),
$\bbox[10px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{{2j \choose j} = {-1/2 \choose j}\pars{-4}^{\,j}}}$ such that
\begin{align}
\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}{2j \choose j}z^{\,j} & =
\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}{-1/2 \choose j}\pars{-4z}^{\,j}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\verts{-4z}\ <\ 1}{=}\,\,\,
\bracks{\vphantom{\large A}1 + \pars{-4z}}^{\,-1/2} = \bbx{{1 \over \root{1 - 4z}}\,,\quad\verts{z} < {1 \over 4}}
\end{align}