# Closed form for: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{{2}^{2n}}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{{(2n+1)}^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Does a closed form of the following sum exist?$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{{2}^{2n}}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{{(2n+1)}^2}$$

Comment: Yes, it exists.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. Starting with
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x^2}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}n x^{2n},
$$
you can perform the following steps to obtain your sum:

- multiply by $x$
- integrate
- divide by $x$
- integrate again
- divide by $x^2$
- set $x=\frac12$

Mathematica says that the ultimate answer is $\frac{\pi\log4}4$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If you want, you can always simplify $\log(4)=2\log(2)$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> [Note that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1991085/85343)
>   $\ds{{2n \choose n} = {-1/2 \choose n}\pars{-4}^{n}}$.

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{2n}}{{2n \choose n} \over \pars{2n + 1}^{2}} & =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-1/2 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}\
\overbrace{\bracks{-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}x^{2n}\,\dd x}}
^{\ds{1 \over \pars{2n + 1}^{2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-1/2 \choose n}\pars{-x^{2}}^{n}
\,\dd x =
-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\pars{1 - x^{2}}^{-1/2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}x^{-1/2}\ln\pars{x}\pars{1 - x}^{-1/2}\,\dd x =
\left. -\,{1 \over 4}\partiald{}{\nu}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\nu - 1/2}
\pars{1 - x}^{-1/2}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] & =
\left. -\,{1 \over 4}\partiald{}{\nu}
{\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1/2}\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{\nu + 1}}\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] & =
\left. -\,{\root{\pi} \over 4}\partiald{}{\nu}
{\Gamma\pars{1/2} + \Gamma\pars{1/2}\Psi\pars{1/2}\nu
\over 1 - \gamma\nu}\,\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] & =
\left. -\,{\pi \over 4}\partiald{}{\nu}
\bracks{1 + \Psi\pars{1 \over 2}\nu}\pars{1 + \gamma\nu}
\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{\pi \over 4}\ \overbrace{\bracks{\Psi\pars{1 \over 2} + \gamma}}
^{\ds{-2\ln\pars{2}}}\ = \bbx{{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{2}\pi} \approx 1.0888
\end{align}