# Two factorials series convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

How to check whether $$\sum_n \frac{(-1)^n (2n)!x^n}{(n!)^2 4^n}$$ converges or diverges. The ratio test is inconclusive and I don't know what to do with $(2n)!$

Comment: Applying Stirling's approximation to both factorials gives a fairly quick answer for the radius of convergence.

Comment: Why do you say the ratio test is inconclusive?  It should settle it easily.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n}\pars{2n}!\, x^{n} \over
\pars{n!}^{2}\, 4^{n}} & =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{2n \choose n}\pars{-\,{x \over 4}}^{n} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{{-1/2 \choose n}\pars{-4}^{n}}
\pars{-\,{x \over 4}}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-1/2 \choose n}x^{n} =
\pars{1 + x}^{-1/2} = \bbx{1 \over \root{1 + x}}
\\[5mm] & \mbox{}
\end{align}

See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1991085/85343).

Note that $\ds{{-1/2 \choose n} \sim {n^{-1/2} \over \root{\pi}}}$ as
$\ds{n \to \infty}$.