# Is $-\int_{0}^{\infty} \bigg( \exp(-\dfrac{\pi}{4}x²)) \bigg) \;dx+\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\bigg( \exp(-\dfrac{\pi}{4}n²)\bigg)=\dfrac12$ true?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, approximation, theta-functions

The following sum may it is easy for computation

$$-\int_{0}^{\infty}  \bigg( \exp(-\dfrac{\pi}{4}x²)) \bigg) \;dx+\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\bigg( \exp(-\dfrac{\pi}{4}n²)\bigg)=\dfrac12$$

The sum LHS can be computed by theta function and the integral by error function which is equal 1 , [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1%2Bsum%28+exp%28-pi%2F4+n%C2%B2%29%29%2C+n%3D0+to+infty+) assumed that difference close to the half integer , But i want to know if the above identity can be considered be true analytically ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the result you gave is analytical. The integral is just a [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#Relation_to_the_gamma_function) and the sum can be computed by the [Jacobi theta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2091197/is-there-a-closed-form-formula-for-sum-limits-n-0-infty-e-n2?noredirect=1&lq=1) as you've said. Both have exact closed forms.

Comment: The closed form for $\theta(i/8)$ is non-trivial, it follows from the theory of elliptic functions, elliptic integrals, modular forms, elliptic curves with complex multiplication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Poisson Summation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula) says
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-\frac\pi4n^2}=2\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-4\pi n^2}\implies
\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\frac\pi4n^2}=\frac32+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-4\pi n^2}
$$
Furthermore, we have the [Gaussian Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=1\implies
\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac\pi4x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=1
$$
Thus,
$$
-\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac\pi4x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x+\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\frac\pi4n^2}
=\frac12+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-4\pi n^2}
$$
Thus, the expression in the question exceeds $\frac12$ by approximately $2e^{-4\pi}\doteq0.000006975$.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfy says

$1/2 (1 + ϑ_3(0, e^{-π/4})) - 1≈0.500006974684712417991279357455722773386084811819343959670243423623882370819559454961925300924629951
$.

So, no.