# What is the relationship between Gaussian integration and discrete Gaussian summation?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm wondering that $\int_{x \in\mathbb{R}}e^{-\pi \frac{x^2}{m^2}} \ \mathrm{d}x  $ is always less than $\sum_{x\in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-\pi \frac{x^2}{m^2}}$ for all real number $m > 0 $.

I know that the former is the Gaussian integral and $\int_{x \in\mathbb{R}}e^{-\pi \frac{x^2}{m^2}} \ \mathrm{d}x= m$, but the latter is the discrete gaussian summation on integer.  I'm not sure if it converges to some function of $m$ or lager than $m$.

I tend to believe the former is less than the latter, for i test a set of value of $m$ in $Maple$ and found that the gap get smaller when $m$ grows.

besides, i found in wikipedia $\sum_{x\in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-\pi {x^2}} = \frac{\pi^{1/4}}{\Gamma{(3/4)}}  $https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series, but i could not find the proof.

Thanks!

Comment: [Proving $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2} = \frac{\sqrt[4] \pi}{\Gamma\left(\frac 3 4\right)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434933/proving-sum-n-infty-infty-e-pi-n2-frac-sqrt4-pi-gamma-left?noredirect=1)

Comment: @Ricky Yes i see, what is the formula of $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-\pi \frac{x^2}{m^2}}$

Comment: I assume that $dx$ should be in the integral?

Comment: @zhw Yes, thanks for the correction. I'll check it right away

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $f$ is positive and strictly decreasing on $[a,b],$ with $0<a<b.$ Then

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx < f(a)(b-a).$$

Comment: I know what you mean, but the rectangle cannot always be above the curve, otherwise, the height of the rectangle would not be equal to the value of the function corresponding to the midpoint of the rectangle

Comment: "Always above" is not necessary. What we have here is $f<f(a)$ on $(a,b],$ and that's enough.

Comment: If so, then you need two  rectangles of height $f(0)$, but the summation only have one.  Maybe I misunderstood it, but I would appreciate it if you could write the detailed proof.