# Prove that $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-e^{-\pi{k\sqrt n}}\right)=\frac{\sqrt2 g_n^2\psi(e^{-\pi\sqrt n})}{e^{\frac{\pi\sqrt n}{12}}}$

Tags: infinite-product, theta-functions

The source of idea is from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ramanujang-andG-Functions.html)

Where $$\psi(q)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}q^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}$$

Prove that,

(1)

$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-e^{-\pi{k\sqrt n}}\right)=\frac{\sqrt2 g_n^2\psi(e^{-\pi\sqrt n})}{e^{\frac{\pi\sqrt n}{12}}}$$

---

On my recent post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793448/prove-left-frace-pi1e-pi-1-cdot-frace3-pi1e3-pi-1-cdot) Paramananad Singh showed that our question is a simple case of Ramanujan $G_n$ and $g_n$ Function. We found another similiar Ramanujan-type infinite product and ask if anyone can help us to prove (1).

We are going to verify (1) numerically

We used the values $g_n$ from [here](https://paramanands.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/ramanujans-class-invariants.html#.V0M7mMR4WrU)

$g_{10}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}}$

$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-e^{-\pi{k\sqrt{10}}}\right)=\frac{\phi\sqrt2 \psi(e^{-\pi\sqrt{10}})}{e^{\frac{\pi\sqrt{10}}{12}}}=0.9999515288...$$

Comment: That's $q$-Pochhammer there; one can maybe use the pentagonal number theorem for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q = e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}}$ and then we need to evaluate the product $$F(q) = \prod_{k = 1}^{\infty}(1 - q^{k})\tag{1}$$ The Ramanujan class invariant $g_{n}$ is given by $$g_{n} = 2^{-1/4}q^{-1/24}\prod_{k = 1}^{\infty}(1 - q^{2k - 1})\tag{2}$$ Next we discuss the Ramanujan theta function $$\psi(q) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}q^{k(k + 1)/2} = \prod_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1 - q^{2k}}{1 - q^{2k - 1}} = \prod_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1 - q^{k}}{(1 - q^{2k - 1})^{2}}\tag{3}$$ From the above equations it is clear that $$\psi(q) = \frac{F(q)}{2^{1/2}q^{-1/12}g_{n}^{2}}$$ and thus $$F(q) = \prod_{k = 1}^{\infty}(1 - e^{-k\pi\sqrt{n}}) = \frac{\sqrt{2}g_{n}^{2}\psi(e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}})}{e^{\pi\sqrt{n}/12}}$$

---

The equality between series and product representation of $\psi(q)$ in $(3)$ is proved via the use of Jacobi Triple Product identity (original proof of this identity by Jacobi is available [here](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/02/elliptic-functions-theta-functions-contd.html)) $$\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}z^{k}q^{k^{2}} = \prod_{k = 1}^{\infty}(1 - q^{2k})(1 + zq^{2k - 1})(1 + z^{-1}q^{2k - 1})\tag{4}$$ by replacing $q$ with $q^{2}$ and $z = q$. With this replacement LHS of $(4)$ is the series representation of $\psi(q)$ and RHS of $(4)$ is the product representation of $\psi(q)$.

Comment: Nicely done thank you @Paramananad Singh.

Comment: @mahdishafici: I added some details on the link between product and series representation of $\psi(q)$. You can have a look at that.