# How can we show that $\ln{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n-1}\over n}\left({12\over e^{n\pi}-1}+{4\over e^{n\pi}+1}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\ln{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n-1}\over n}\left({12\over e^{n\pi}-1}+{4\over e^{n\pi}+1}\right)\tag1$$

Any hints?

Comment: Where did you come across this?

Comment: I have seen in past many questions from you based on Ramanujan's theory of theta functions. You should have a look at this link http://www.genautica.com/math/e_and_pi/e_pi_integer_multiples.html which gives many similar sums all of which can be proved in similar manner using theory of theta functions.

Comment: Questions which merely state a problem are discouraged on this site. Please edit your post to add additional context: where did the problem arise? Why is it of interest? What methods have you attempted to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

We have that
$${1\over e^{n\pi}-1}={e^{-n\pi}\over 1-e^{-n\pi}}=\sum_{k\geq 1}e^{-nk\pi}$$
and
$${1\over e^{n\pi}+1}={e^{-n\pi}\over 1+e^{-n\pi}}=-\sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^ke^{-nk\pi}.$$
Hence
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n-1}\over n}&\left(12\sum_{k\geq 1}e^{-nk\pi}-4\sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^ke^{-nk\pi}\right)\\
&=4\sum_{k\geq 1}\left(3-(-1)^k \right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n-1}\over n}e^{-nk\pi}\\
&=4\sum_{k\geq 1}\left(3-(-1)^k \right)\ln(1+e^{-k\pi})\\
&=8\sum_{k\geq 1}\ln(1+e^{-k\pi})+8\sum_{k\geq 1}\ln(1+e^{-(2k-1)\pi})\\
&=8\ln\left(\prod_{k\geq 1}(1+e^{-k\pi})(1+e^{-(2k-1)\pi})\right)\\
&=8\ln\left(\prod_{k\geq 1}\frac{(1+e^{-(2k-1)\pi})}{(1-e^{-(2k-1)\pi})}\right)
+8\ln\left(\prod_{k\geq 1}(1+e^{-k\pi})(1-e^{-(2k-1)\pi})\right)\\
&=\ln(2)
\end{align*}
where in the last step we use [Prove $\left(\frac{e^{\pi}+1}{e^{\pi}-1}\cdot\frac{e^{3\pi}+1}{e^{3\pi}-1}\cdot\frac{e^{5\pi}+1}{e^{5\pi}-1}\cdots\right)^8=2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793448/prove-left-frace-pi1e-pi-1-cdot-frace3-pi1e3-pi-1-cdot?noredirect=1&lq=1)
and 
$$\prod_{k\geq 1}(1+e^{-k\pi})(1-e^{-(2k-1)\pi})=
\prod_{k\geq 1}\frac{(1-e^{-2k\pi})(1-e^{-(2k-1)\pi})}{(1-e^{-k\pi})}=1.$$

Comment: Nice use of the linked result. +1

Comment: it appears to be a case of serial downvoting, my answer got downvoted too!

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of theory of theta functions. Let $0 < q < 1$ and $$a(q) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{q^{n}}{n(1 - q^{n})}$$ Next we can see that \begin{align}
b(q) &= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n - 1}\cdot\frac{q^{n}}{n(1 - q^{n})}\notag\\
&= \sum_{n \text{ odd}}\frac{q^{n}}{n(1 - q^{n})} - \sum_{n \text{ even}}\frac{q^{n}}{n(1 - q^{n})}\notag\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{q^{n}}{n(1 - q^{n})} - 2\sum_{n \text{ even}}\frac{q^{n}}{n(1 - q^{n})}\notag\\
&= a(q) - a(q^{2})\notag
\end{align}
Similarly we can prove that $$c(q) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{q^{n}}{n(1 + q^{n})} = a(q) - 2a(q^{2})$$ and $$d(q) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n - 1}\frac{q^{n}}{n(1 + q^{n})} = c(q) - c(q^{2})$$ i.e $$d(q) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n - 1}\frac{q^{n}}{n(1 + q^{n})} = a(q) - 3a(q^{2}) + 2a(q^{4})$$ The sum in question is $$S = 12b(q) + 4d(q) = 16a(q) - 24a(q^{2}) + 8a(q^{4})\tag{1}$$ where $q =  e^{-\pi}$. We can see from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/938644/72031) that
\begin{align}
a(q) &= -\frac{\log kk'^{4}}{12} - \frac{\log 2}{3} - \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{K}{\pi}\right) - \frac{\pi K'}{24K}\tag{2}\\
a(q^{2}) &= -\frac{\log kk'}{6} - \frac{\log 2}{6} - \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{K}{\pi}\right) - \frac{\pi K'}{12K}\tag{3}\\
a(q^{4}) &= -\frac{\log k^{4}k'}{12} + \frac{\log 2}{6} - \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{K}{\pi}\right) - \frac{\pi K'}{6K}\tag{4}
\end{align}
Since $q = e^{-\pi}$ it follows from theory of theta functions and elliptic integrals that $K' = K$ and $k = k' = 1/\sqrt{2}$. Thus $$a(q) = -\frac{\log 2}{8} - \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{K}{\pi}\right) - \frac{\pi}{24}$$ and $$a(q^{2}) = -\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{K}{\pi}\right) - \frac{\pi}{12}$$ and $$a(q^{4}) = \frac{3\log 2}{8} - \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{K}{\pi}\right) - \frac{\pi}{6}$$ and then from $(1)$ we get $S = \log 2$.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: I hope I can be of use here and you see this before the question gets closed.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we seek to verify that

$$\log 2 = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}
\left(\frac{12}{\exp(n\pi)-1} + \frac{4}{\exp(n\pi)+1}\right).$$

I present some functional equations which however do not suffice for a
proof but may perhaps serve as a starting point. The reader is invited
to supply the missing equations as conjectures for eventual proof. The
computational details are available on request.

We make the following definitions:

$$S_1(x) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}
\frac{\exp(nx)}{\exp(2nx)-1}$$

and

$$S_2(x) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}
\frac{1}{\exp(2nx)-1}$$

with $x\ge 0.$ We are interested in

$$16S_1(\pi) + 8S_2(\pi)
\quad\text{i.e.}\quad T(x) = 2S_1(x)+S_2(x).$$

We also use

$$S_3(x) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n}
\frac{\exp(nx)}{\exp(2nx)-1}$$

and

$$S_4(x) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{\exp(nx)-1}$$
so that

$$S_3(x) = S_4(x)-S_4(2x).$$

We then obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]
{S_1(x) = \frac{\pi^2}{24x}  -\frac{x}{24}
+ S_1(\pi^2/x)}$$

and

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]
{S_3(x) = \frac{\pi^2}{12x}  -\frac{1}{2}\log 2
+ \frac{x}{24} - S_3(2\pi^2/x)}$$

and

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]
{S_4(x) = \frac{\pi^2}{6x}  -\frac{1}{2}\log (2\pi)
+ \frac{1}{2}\log x - \frac{x}{24}
+ S_4(4\pi^2/x).}$$

Most importantly we get

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]
{T(x) = \frac{\pi^2}{8x}  -\frac{1}{2}\log 2
+ 2T(\pi^2/x)
- 3S_3(\pi^2/x)}$$

which has the alternate form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]
{T(x) = \frac{\pi^2}{8x}  -\frac{1}{2}\log 2
+ S_1(\pi^2/x)
- S_3(2\pi^2/x).}$$