# Seeking for $\alpha\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{k-1}\over k(e^{k\pi}-1)}+\beta\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{k-1}\over k(e^{k\pi}+1)}=f(\alpha,\beta)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, closed-form

We are seeking the closed form of $f(\alpha,\beta)$

Let

> $$P=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{k-1}\over k(e^{k\pi}-1)}$$ and
>
> $$Q=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{k-1}\over k(e^{k\pi}+1)}$$

We have a closed form of

$$\ln(2)=12P+4Q$$

Let $$\alpha P+\beta Q=f(\alpha,\beta)$$

We are assuming that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are integers

**We are wondering if there is a closed form for $f(\alpha,\beta)?$**

Comment: Aren't $P$ and $Q$ constants?

Comment: Have a look at *I.J.Zucker - THE SUMMATION OF SERIES OF HYPERBOLIC FUNCTIONS, 1979*.

Comment: You may have a look at this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1912949/72031 where it is established that $\log 2=12P+4Q$. You can get values of $P, Q$ in closed form using this technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P + Q = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left ( \sum_{k=1}^{n}{(-1)^{k-1}\over k(e^{k\pi}-1)} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}{(-1)^{k-1}\over k(e^{k\pi}+1)}\right )$$

$$P + Q = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left ( \sum_{k=1}^{n}{(-1)^{k-1}\over k} \left({1 \over e^{k\pi}-1} + {1 \over e^{k\pi}+1} \right )\right )$$

$$P + Q = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left ( \sum_{k=1}^{n}{(-1)^{k-1}\over k} \left({2e^{\pi k} \over (e^{k\pi}-1)(e^{k\pi}+1)} \right )\right )$$

$$P + Q = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left ( \sum_{k=1}^{n}{(-1)^{k-1}\over k} \text{csch}(\pi k)\right )$$

$$P + Q = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{ \text{csch}(\pi k)}{k} = \frac{1}{12}(\ln(64) - \pi)$$

The final identity was derived using Wolfram Alpha, but was a mystery to me. I asked a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2330348/why-is-sum-k-1-infty-1k1-frac-textcsch-pi-kk-frac12) to demystify it, which Jack D'Aurizio answered.

We have $P + Q = \frac{1}{12}(\ln(64) - \pi)$ and $12P + 4Q = \ln(2)$, giving us:

$$P = -\frac{1}{24}(\ln(8) - \pi), \quad Q = \frac{1}{8}(\ln(32) - \pi)$$

Comment: @orip please explain how you got $P+Q = \frac{1}{2}(\ln(64) - \pi)$ from the Sum?

Comment: @unseen_rider I added the derivation of $\text{csch}$, sadly the most interesting part was found with Wolfram Alpha - I'm still searching a reference for the identity.

Comment: @unseen_rider I asked a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2330348/why-is-sum-k-1-infty-1k1-frac-textcsch-pi-kk-frac12) for the identity, which Jack D'Aurizio answered.

Comment: That should be $\frac{1}{12}(\log{(64)} - \pi)$ here and in the other question.

Comment: @sharding4 Oops, fixed.

Comment: @NightOfPower Excuse me?