# Evaluating $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1 + x ^4 } \, d x $

Tags: calculus

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\,1 + x^{4}\,}\,\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

I used substitution of tanx=z but it was not fruitful. Then i used $ (x-1/x)= z$ and
$(x)^2-1/(x)^2=z $ but no helpful expression was derived.
I also used property $\int_0^a f(a-x)=\int_0^a f(x) $
Please help me out

Comment: Throw the command `Int[Sqrt[1+x^4],{x,0,1}]` to [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/), the integral evaluates to ${}_2F_1(-\frac12, \frac14; -\frac54; -1 ) \approx 1.0894294132248223224\ldots$ where ${}_2F_1$ is the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). There is probably no 
elementary way to evaluate the integral.

Comment: Thank you...trying to understant your answer

Answer (score 23):

We can do better than hypergeometric function and elliptic integral:
$$\color{blue}{\int_0^1 {\sqrt {1 + {x^4}} dx}  = \frac{{\sqrt 2 }}{3} + \frac{{{\Gamma ^2}(\frac{1}{4})}}{{12\sqrt \pi  }}}$$

---

Firstly, integration by part gives
$$\int_0^1 {\sqrt {1 + {x^4}} dx}  = \sqrt 2  - 2\int_0^1 {\frac{{{x^4}}}{{\sqrt {1 + {x^4}} }}dx}  = \sqrt 2  - 2\int_0^1 {\left( {\sqrt {1 + {x^4}}  - \frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + {x^4}} }}} \right)dx} $$
Hence
$$\int_0^1 {\sqrt {1 + {x^4}} dx}  = \frac{{\sqrt 2 }}{3} + \frac{2}{3}\int_0^1 {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + {x^4}} }}dx} $$
Making $x=1/u$ in the last integral gives
$$\int_0^1 {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + {x^4}} }}dx}  = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + {x^4}} }}} dx = \frac{1}{{8\sqrt \pi  }}{\Gamma ^2}(\frac{1}{4})$$
which can be evaluated by using some formula for [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: +1 cool. it is nice to see one can replace the hypergeometric function by the more elementary gamma function.

Comment: This is same as Robert Israel 's evaluation but in a different way.  The value $K(1/\sqrt{2})$ is evaluated in terms of Beta/Gamma function as $\Gamma^{2}(1/4)/(4\sqrt{\pi})$.

Comment: See the evaluation of $K(1/\sqrt{2})$ at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1793756/72031

Comment: Btw in general if $y^{2}=p(x)$ where $p(x) $ is a polynomial of degree $3$ or $4$ and $R(x, y) $ is a rational function of two variables then the integral $\int R(x, y) \, dx$ is non-elementary and can be evaluating terms of elliptic integrals. So looking at the integrand $\sqrt{1+x^{4}}$ it is reasonable to expect elliptic integrals. But your technique appears to be very simple because it avoids the difficult theory of elliptic integrals. +1 already provided for your nice answer.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the ${}_{2}F_{1}$ hypergeometric integral form given by
$${}_{2}F_{1}(a, b; c; x) = \frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(b) \, \Gamma(c-b)} \, \int_{0}^{1} t^{b-1} \, (1-t)^{c-b-1} \, (1-x \, t)^{-a} \, dt$$
leads to, with $a=-1/2$, $b=1/4$, $c=5/4$, $x=-1$,
$${}_{2}F_{1}\left(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}; \frac{5}{4}; -1\right) = \frac{1}{4} \, \int_{0}^{1} t^{-3/4} \, \sqrt{1+ t} \, dt.$$
Now let $t = x^{4}$ to obtain
$$\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1 + x^4} \, dx = {}_{2}F_{1}\left(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}; \frac{5}{4}; -1\right) = 1.08943...$$

Answer (score 5):

We can do better than elliptic integrals or $\Gamma$ / Beta / hypergeometric functions:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+t^4}\,dt = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}+\frac{\pi}{6\,\text{AGM}\left(1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)} \tag{1}$$
due to integration by parts and what is shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2721116/44121). $(1)$ summarizes a very efficient numerical technique (the $\text{AGM}$ iteration has a quadratic convergence) for computing arbitrarily accurate numerical approximations of the LHS. It also shows
$$ 1.084\ldots=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}+\frac{\pi}{3}(2-\sqrt{2})\leq \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+t^4}\,dt\leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}+\frac{\pi}{6}2^{1/4}=1.094\ldots\tag{2}$$
Improving the bound $\leq\sqrt{\frac{6}{5}}$ given by Jensen's inequality.
 Your integral is strictly related to the [lemniscate constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LemniscateConstant.html).

Answer (score 3):

Integration by parts gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+x^4} d x \\
& =\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} d x+\int_0^1 \frac{x^4}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} d x \\
& =\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} d x+\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 x d\left(\sqrt{1+x^4}\right) \\
& =\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} d x+\frac{1}{2}\left[x \sqrt{1+x^4}\right]_0^1-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+x^4} d x \\
\therefore I & =\frac{2}{3} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} d x+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}
\end{aligned}
$$
For the first integral, letting $x^2=\tan \theta$ transforms it into
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} d x & =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos \theta \sin \theta}} d \theta \\
& =\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{2\left(\frac{1}{4} \right) -1} \theta \cos ^{2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1} d \theta\\&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8} B\left(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}\right)\\&= \frac{1}{8 \sqrt{\pi}} \Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \quad \left(\textrm{ By } \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)=\pi \csc \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \right)\end{aligned}
$$
Hence $$\boxed{I=\frac{1}{12 \sqrt{\pi}} \Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) +\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}} $$

Answer (score 2):

Another non-elementary answer, from Maple, is 
$$ \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+x^4}\; dx = \frac{\sqrt {2}+{\it EllipticK} \left( 1/\sqrt {2} \right)}{3} $$

Comment: Thank you  very much @ Robert

Answer (score 1):

For an approximation, you could use a Padé approximant for the integrand. The simplest one would be
$$\frac{3 x^4+4}{x^4+4}=3-\frac{x+2}{x^2+2 x+2}+\frac{x-2}{x^2-2 x+2}$$
$$\int \frac{3 x^4+4}{x^4+4}\,dx=3x+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{x^2-2 x+2}{x^2+2 x+2}\right)+\tan ^{-1}(1-x)-\tan ^{-1}(1+x)$$ So, using the given bounds, an approximation is 
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\,1 + x^{4}\,}\,\,dx \approx 3-\frac{\log (5)}{2}-\tan ^{-1}(2)\approx 1.08813$$