# $\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[]{1+t^4}dt$

Tags: integration

I tried by using $t^2$ = $tan\theta$ and then by inserting $t^4$ by $tan^2\theta$ in $\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[]{1+t^4}dt$, I get $dt$ = $\frac{sec^2\theta\times d\theta}{2\times \sqrt[]{tan\theta}}$ &  $\sqrt[]{1+t^4}$ = $sec\theta$. Thus the integration becomes $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{sec^3 \theta \times d\theta}{2\times \sqrt{tan\theta}}$
What to do after this step?
I have tried to do this which I have mistakenly written in the answer column.
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+t^4}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1+t^4}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^4}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}+\int_{0}^{1}t\cdot\frac{t^3}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}+\left[\frac12t\sqrt{1+t^4}\right]_{0}^{1}-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+t^4}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}+\frac121\sqrt{1+1^4}-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+t^4}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
\implies \frac32\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+t^4}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+1^4}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\\
\implies \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+t^4}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{1+1^4}+\frac23\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}.\\
\end{align}

Comment: This is not an elementary integral.

Comment: Sorry it is a definite integral but I believe I have got the problem

Comment: There is not simple way to evaluate this integral exactly without invoking special functions. The value of this integral (numerically) is 1.09

Comment: WA sasy the answer is given by $$\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{2} \left(1+(1+i)
   F\left(\left.\frac{1}{2} i \log \left((1+2
   i)-2 \sqrt{-1+i}\right)\right|-1\right)\right)$$

Comment: The integral is not elementary, but can be expressed in terms of gamma function only. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311583

Comment: @Dr.onnhard Graubner Can you please show how to arrive at this expression?

Comment: Oh no no I did not duplicate it meaning copied it. This is how I tried earlier but I was stuck with the denominator $\sqrt{1+t^4}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+t^4}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1+t^4}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^4}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}+\int_{0}^{1}t\cdot\frac{t^3}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}+\left[\frac12t\sqrt{1+t^4}\right]_{0}^{1}-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+t^4}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}+\frac121\sqrt{1+1^4}-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+t^4}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
\implies \frac32\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+t^4}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+1^4}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\\
\implies \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+t^4}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{1+1^4}+\frac23\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}.\\
\end{align}

Comment: Can anyone suggest how to arrive at a definitive answer after this ?